# How to convert Java Object to JsonStream with Object as container by GSon

Tags: java, json, gson

i got some object like this

```
public class Task {

private String uuid;
private String taskName;
private String description;
...
}
```

and parse it with GSon.toJSon

```
jsonString = gson.toJson(myTask);
```

write it in a file which looks like

```
{"uuid":"d594dc13-13d5-4f6a-b7f5-c30c2e52e1b2","taskName":"some taskname","description":"some description" ... }
```

Now i would like to have something like a container around those parameters:

```
Task{"uuid":"d594dc13-13d5-4f6a-b7f5-c30c2e52e1b2","taskName":"some taskname","description":"some description" ... }
```

How can i do it?

I odnt use Jackson library only Gson from google.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `String jsonString = myTask.getClass().getSimpleName()+ new Gson().toJson(myTask);`? (or you can write the class name to the file before).

Comment: Good enough :) But i thought there would be something default by using the Gson.toJson(..) or Gsonbuilder in the right way.

Comment: Well `Task{ ... }` wouldn't be a valid JSON output, so I don't expect that you can tweak the parser to get an output that wouldn't be conformed to the JSON grammar.

Comment: you are right i just got the com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException ...